# EMI input filter for low frequency heater controller

Tags: pwm, buck, emc, emi-filtering

A meanwell 24V, 280W AC-DC power adapter is used to supply a PWM-driven heater control circuit.
The power adapter is fully enclosed and protected (model GST280A24).
The load is a pure resistive ceramic heater, it draws 10A at maximum duty cycle. The PWM is a 5V logic signal, with a carrier frequency of 60 Hz. The mosfet is driven to turn-on slowly, to avoid painful spikes and ringing.
The goal here is to design a circuit which is able to pass EN 55011 conducted and radiated emissions with a good margin. Is an input filter required? If yes, which topology and values should be used? I am familiar with input filters for higher frequency buck converters, but I never dealt with such low frequencies.

[image]

Comment: What about the Meanwell power supply - have you checked that it will pass? What port has to pass? What is the cable lengths and dispositions of those cables? These are fundamental factors in determining what might pass and what won't pass.

Comment: @Andyaka, yes the meanwell will pass. The cable length and all other recommendations are fully respected. The power supply cable is connected directly to the board with an approved connector. We already tested several of these power adapters and did not find any problem. The question here is regarding the circuit itself. Filtering 60 Hz with a LC low-pass filter seems impossible due to the required values of L and C. But maybe filtering higher armonics would be necessary? Choosing a cut-off frequency of 100 kHz or something, is that good/necessary?

Comment: What port has to pass?

Comment: Dear @Andyaka what do you mean by port? The power adapter is connected to mains with a standard C13/C14 connector. The DC side is connected to the control card with a high current MOLEX 6 pin connector.

Comment: Conducted emissions are relative to a port on the circuit.

Comment: The control circuit input port is a screw terminal, wired to the power adapter connector with a cable with ring terminals.

Answer (score 0):

> Is an input filter required?

No, it's not required, but the 240W load is a large fraction (~85%) of the supplies maximum output power. In the past I have had issues with cheaper supplies like meanwell and getting them to pass conducted emissions testing or even regulate well (some had inductors that would whine) with a PWM. The problem isn't so much filtering, as much as energy storage, because the supplies control loop has a hard time keeping up with the load. The best way to tell is just look at voltage output of the supply when the heater is switching, and if it's more than the ripple rating in the datasheet (200mVpp in your case) then you might have a problem.

Keep in mind that many supplies are designed and tested for mostly fixed loads.

> If yes, which topology and values should be used?

It really depends on the impedance response of the supply (which is not in the datasheet), which means that you would have to test to find the source impedance or ask the manufacturer for it. If you know the source impedance of the supply (which is probably complex at 60Hz) you could tune the load somewhat to that of the source. One problem is power caps often involves large capacitors, which could also cause other regulatory problems (like not meeting the 30second rule, or long startup times).

Sometimes moving to a faster switching frequency can be beneficial, but too fast can interfere with the control loop (you would not want the load to be switching at the same frequency as the supplies control loop).